# Run threads across multiple computers by pthread?

Tags: pthreads, cloud

My question is how to run a multi-threaded program in C by pthread across multiple computers?
Is it possible?

Comment: I think you rather need clustering like Message Passing Interface for this, not threads. Threads aren't made for this, even if it should work, the performance will be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running program across multiple computers might not be possible with `multi-threading` try using `multiple processes` as @goldenmean has suggested.

PS:You can find my tutorials online this type of application can be easily done using `MPI`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pthreads library alone would not help you to execute a distributed version of your code/application on different physical CPUs/machines. For that you might need to see how the below libraries/frameworks for distributed computing work

-- Message Passing Interface (MPI)

-- Hadoop and MapReduce

-- Write your own distributed parallel programming framework using the basic building blocks